# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode, when uploading from testscript

Tags: python, django

I am making test script to upload excel file,

```
def test_upload(self):
    c = Client()
    with open('_material/trick.xlsx') as fp:
        c.post('/cms/template/up', {'name': 'fred','content_file': fp})
```

There comes the error

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 16: invalid start byte`

However in html upload form, there is no error occurs.

```
class UploadTemplateFileForm(BaseModelForm):
    content_file = forms.FileField(required=True)
```

Why this difference occurs?

Comment: xlsx files are binary. you need to open with mode `'rb'`, not the default `'r'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.xlsx files are binary (they are actually pkzip archives).  You must do `open('_material/trick.xlsx','rb')`.

Comment: Thank you very much , it saves my life.